# Variable 'general_log_file' can't be set to the value of '/var/lib/msyql/ubuntu.log'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, mysql5.5

I changed the value of mysql's `general_log_file` variable to something else, and now I'm trying to change it back to what it was originally, `/var/lib/mysql/ubuntu.log`. But when I do:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log_file = '/var/lib/msyql/ubuntu.log';
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'general_log_file' can't be set to the
>   value of '/var/lib/msyql/ubuntu.log'

What's going on?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> `ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'general_log_file' can't be set to the
>   value of '/var/lib/msyql/ubuntu.log'`
>
> What's going on?

The simple answer is this file doesn't exist.

You type too fast. There is a typo in the file name, it should be `/var/lib/mysql/ubuntu.log`.

Comment: If the folder exists, it might need appropriate permissions for the `mysql` user (or whoever owns the `mysqld` process) to write to it.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a very old answer, but just in case someone else will be looking for an answer here.

In my case - the problem was in permissions that wasn't correct on the destination folder.

Comment: I'd upvote your answer if you could be more precise about what permissions you had, and what you found you needed (and that wasn't `777`).

Comment: I had permission for root only to write into that directory. meaning mysql user had no permission to write to it. From here - you have several options to fix this. add 777 permissions (as i did) or create a directory for the mysql user to write to it.

Comment: `777` permissions is a very poor idea indeed.

Comment: in my case - it was not bad idea at all, as this is a "junk" folder that i want to write to it from anywhere. I wasn't setting the file to be written to /var/lib/mysql/ubuntu.log as in the question, that is why i didn't added the idea of 777 at the first place. just noting that even if the folder exists - it worth checking that it has correct permissions.

Answer (score 3):

This is what helped me in a similar situation:

1. **Create a new folder** somewhere on your machine, like so (of course, you can name the folder anything you want):

> $ mkdir ~/log_files

2. **Change ownership** of this folder to `mysql`:

> $ chown mysql: ~/log_files

3. **Set the the variable** `general_log_file` to the folder you just created in your mysql console, like so:

> mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log_file = '~/log_files/mysql_log.log';

4. **Restart mysql** (terminal command can be googled for your specific setup, e.g. by searching for "bitnami mysql restart")
5. **Check**, if the log file exists in the folder you created in step 1

I hope it helps!

Comment: Just want you to know that your answer is the only thing that worked for me. changing ownership to mysql was what was missing for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I was trying to create a log file on my local machine when I was running mysql in a Docker container. I was able to launch the CLI for docker and get into container and tail the log file there.